# Unable to connect to Azure staging web role but can RDP and run it

Tags: azure

I have a Web Role currently loaded on staging. When I try and connect to it via the DNS name given ( .cloudapp.net ) I am unable to connect. If I RDP into the staging instance I can run the web site via IP locally but just not externally. Is there any reason this would be?

Update: I tried to connect with Fiddler running and got this message:

[Fiddler] Connection to cf4ef419bd7e45ba8b1e83bb9b27ed64.cloudapp.net failed.
Exception Text: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx:80

Comment: When you RDP in and view the website, what port is it on? (I'm wondering if somehow your endpoint is configured for something other than port 80.) If you can post your ServiceDefinition.csdef, we can eyeball it and make sure it looks right...

Comment: Further to @smarx's comment: if your site is set up as HTTPS then Azure Management Portal will give the URL as http: rather than https:, causing this behaviour (because it is listening on port 443).  (Gets me every time.)

Comment: Oliver, that was the answer. It is SSL only (although I am sure I didn't have this problem previously). As soon as I change the url to https it works. You should add comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Olivers comment helped me.  I opened the web role using remote desktop and found it to be on 8080.  I fixed that in the ServiceDefinition file, redeployed...and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to promote someone's comment to an answer? Oliver is right, browsing to https://cf4ef419bd7e45ba8b1e83bb9b27ed64.cloudapp.net (HTTPS) works, which means there is presumably only an HTTPS endpoint. Add an HTTP endpoint if you want HTTP to work too.

Comment: You can flag the comment, select `Other`, then say that it should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Craig, did you just recently provision the hosted service? If so, it can take a few minutes to a couple of hours for the DNS servers to pick up the new DNS name and subsequently to have it resolve on your end.

Comment: No, service has been running for a year. Did recently upgrade to Azure SDK 1.4 though. It has been 8 hours since staging was deployed.

Comment: It should never take more than a couple minutes for the DNS name to start working.